# Cross-referencing within documents with R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I have a very simple document in R Markdown. Here is the code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

# R Markdown {#r-mkdw}


This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. I want to cross-reference the Header of this text with \@ref(r-mkdw).
```

But the cross-reference as the manual specifies doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" rmarkdown package with `html_output` does not support cross referencing. You have to use, e.g. the package `bookdown` which provides the format `html_document2`.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2
---
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a separate _output.yml file with "--- bookdown::html_document2: default
bookdown::gitbook" and still, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you Provide your Project?

Comment: What do you mean by Project?

Comment: ALSO, THIS DOESN'T WORK---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2
---
# R Markdown


This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. I want to cross-reference the Header of this text with \@ref(sec:r-markdown).

Comment: but it works if you add this to your header `# R Markdown {#r-mkdw}`. Then you can refer to that with `\@ref(r-mkdw)`.

Comment: No. it's so strange, no idea what's going on.